# Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

So I recently was doing a Angular course and I found myself stuck with this error [appcomponent.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkRIp.png) I tried to find answers in here but all of them are outdated.

**appcomponent.ts**

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  divisions$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.divisions$ = db.list('/divisions').valueChanges();
  }

  add(division: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.divisions$.push(division.value);
    division.value = '';
  }
}
```

Any help is accepted,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this.divisions$` is an Observable of list of any (`divisions$: Observable<any[]>;`) and you want to make some addition to that list, you can use tap:

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.divisions$.pipe(tap(currentList=> {
  currentList.push(newData);
}));
```

You can also create a service and return just a any[] and use it directly in your ts file.

Furthermore, I do not recommend the use of `any`, I advise you to create an interface that matches the data returned by your API and replace `any[]` by `YOUR_INTERFACE[]`

Comment: Alright, seems that your answer is making my project start walking again! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want is to push an element into the list, which will be returned by `this.division$`, whenever `add()` is triggered.

However what you are doing is you directly use `this.division$`, which is an Observable, so of course it doesn't have  `push()` function, hence the error shows.

So you have to first get the array from which `this.division$` will return, either by:

- `this.division$.subscribe(array=> array.push(division.value))` (this looks kinda ugly..)
- Or just do as @quentin wrote